# How to use Array to display the correct information using ID as index?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, hyperlink

I'm currently learning a very basic web programming subject but I'm having a problem to get a project done.

The code below displays all the hyperlink that I have created, when I click on the link, it will display different information according to the information that I want it to display( the code is after the hyerlink code).
I have used if-else command but is there anyway that I can use Array to store the informaion? I have tried doing so many but I just dont seem to get it right for Array.

This code is the hyperlink page.

```
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Welcome to School of IIT</h1>
<p>Please choose a diploma you are interested in:</p>

<ul>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=1">Diploma in IT</a></li>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=2">Diploma in Internet and Multimedia Design</a></li>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=3">Diploma in Mobile and Wireless</a></li>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=4">Diploma in Financial Business Informatics</a></li>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=5">Diploma in Cyber and Digital Security</a></li>
<li><a href="dipListShow.php?dip_id=6">Diploma in Gaming and    Entertainment Technology</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

This code is the php page:

```
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Welcome to School of Informatics and IT School</h1>
<?php
$dip_id = $_GET['dip_id'];
if ($dip_id == "1")
{
 $dipname = "Diploma in Information Technology";
 $imgfile= "dip_it.jpg";
 echo "<font color = red>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
else if($dip_id == "2")
{
  $dipname = "Diploma in Interactive Multimedia Informatics";
  $imgfile= "dip_imd.jpg";
  echo "<font color = green>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
else if($dip_id == "3")
{
  $dipname = "Diploma in Mobile and Wireless Technology";
  $imgfile= "dip_mwc.jpg";
  echo "<font color = blue>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
else if($dip_id == "4")
{
  $dipname = "Diploma in Financial Business Informatics";
  $imgfile= "dip_fbi.jpg";
  echo "<font color = purple>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
else if($dip_id == "5")
{
  $dipname = "Diploma in Cyber and Digital Security";
  $imgfile= "dip_cds.jpg";
  echo "<font color = orange>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
else if($dip_id == "6")
{
  $dipname = "Diploma in Gaming and Entertainment Technology";
  $imgfile= "dip_get.jpg";
  echo "<font color = grey>You have selected $dipname</font></p>";
}
echo "<img src='images/$imgfile'/>";
?>
</body>
```

Please guide me on how to get this done in Array rather than using if-else and also how to link between the two pages. Thank you :)

Comment: If you have database then you should store those information in the database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use database.Store this information in the table and retrieve it by its id. 
database structure should be like this:

```
table_name
 -id
 -tipname
 -image
```

**Or using Array(it is not good practice):**
**Live Demo :** https://eval.in/84787
Set correct value in the  corresponding key. I have insert test value

```
 <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Welcome to School of Informatics and IT School</h1>
    <?php
     $dip_id = isset($_GET['dip_id']) ? $_GET['dip_id']: '';
     // set your $dip_id for testing purpose
     //$dip_id = 3;
        $arrData = array("1" => array( "dpname" =>"Diploma in Information Technology","image" =>"dip_it.jpg","color"=>"color1"),"2" => array( "dpname" =>"Diploma in Interactive Multimedia Informatics","image" =>"dip_imd.jpg","color"=>"color1"),"3" => array( "dpname" =>"Diploma in Mobile and Wireless Technology","image" =>"dip_it.jpg","color"=>"color1"),"4" => array( "dpname" =>"set value for 4","image" =>"set value for 4","color"=>"color1"),"5" => array( "dpname" =>"set value for 5","image" =>"set value for 5","color"=>"color5"),"6" => array( "dpname" =>"set value for 4","image" =>"set value for 4","color"=>"color6"));

        if(isset($dip_id) || $dip_id){
         echo "<font color = '{$arrData[$dip_id]['color']}'>You have selected    {$arrData[$dip_id]['dpname']}</font></p>";
         $img = $arrData[$dip_id]['image'];

         echo "<img src='Assignment_1/$img'/>";

    }

    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: The problem is i have not learn how to store information into a database :(.

Comment: @Kiwakosan : For dynamic web sites you should use database. I also answered for alternative way( using Array). did you try it?

Comment: $dip_id = $_GET['dip_id'];// it said here  "Undefined index: dip_id "
    echo "<font color = {$arrData[$dip_id]['color']}>You have selected {$arrData[$dip_id]['dpname']}</font></p>"; // it said here  Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\1300532g\Assignment_1\FashionDtPg.php on line 15

Comment: @Kiwakosan : can you try it again? I have edited my answer. I also give you a link to test it in online. let me know your feedback.

Comment: There is no error now :) but it can't get image to display. Is there another code to put image into array :O ? thank you so much!

Comment: Can you tell me your image directory? e.g( localhost/images/)

Comment: the image files are inside the Assignment folder XD thank you so much :3

Comment: In current code I am looking for images in the your_project/images/dip_it.jpg. Is that correct path for your image?

Comment: @Kiwakosan : If it worked please Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.It will be a green mark if it is accepted correctly.

Comment: why can't i accept both answer? because @Manish answer's also work as well :3 ? so i can only choose one ?

Comment: what does this ? $_GET['dip_id']: ''; means?

Answer (score 0):

The follwoing code will work only if your diploma id is in sequential.

```
$data = array (
        array (
                'dipName' => 'Diploma in Information Technology',
                'img' => 'dip_it.jpg',
                'color' => 'red' 
        ),
        array (
                'dipName' => 'Diploma in Interactive Multimedia Informatics',
                'img' => 'dip_imd.jpg',
                'color' => 'green'
        ),
        array (
                'dipName' => 'Diploma in Mobile and Wireless Technology',
                'img' => 'dip_mwc.jpg',
                'color' => 'blue'
        ),
        array (
                'dipName' => 'Diploma in Interactive Multimedia Informatics',
                'img' => 'dip_imd.jpg',
                'color' => 'red'
        )
);


echo '<font color = "'.$data[$dip_id]['color'].'">You have selected '.$data[$dip_id]['dipName'];
echo '<img src="images/'.$data[$dip_id]['img'].'"/>';
```

Comment: thank you its work ! I just need to define <br/> $dip_id = $_GET['dip_id']; <br/> Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this. If you want a simple array, just do something like this:

```
$dip_ids = array(
    '1' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Information Technology",
        'imgfile' => "dip_it.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = red>You have selected $dipname</font></p>"
        ),
    '2' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Interactive Multimedia Informatics",
        'imgfile' => "dip_imd.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = green>You have selected $dipname</font></p>"
        ),
    '3' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Mobile and Wireless Technology",
        'imgfile' => "dip_mwc.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = blue>You have selected $dipname</font></p>"
        ),
    '4' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Financial Business Informatics",
        'imgfile' => "dip_fbi.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = purple>You have selected $dipname</font></p>"
        ),
    '5' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Cyber and Digital Security",
        'imgfile' => "dip_cds.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = orange>You have selected $dipname</font></p>"
        ),
    '6' => array(
        'dipname' => "Diploma in Gaming and Entertainment Technology",
        'imgfile' => "dip_get.jpg",
        'msg' =>"<font color = grey>You have selected $dipname</font></p>",
        )
    );
```

Then just access the data like `$dip_ids[$dip_id]['dipname']`, etc.